# Python 3.0: Looping list index that is "out of range"

Tags: python, string, loops, indexing, range

Okay so basically, I need a bit of help with this very easy program I've threw together:

```
from graphics import *

def main():
win = GraphWin("Text Window", 400, 600)
options = ["Hello", "How", "Are", "You"]
x = 200
y = 20
for i in range(4):
    message = Text(Point(x,y), options[i])
    message.draw(win)
    y = y + 30

main()
```

Don't worry about the 'graphics' module. It's part of John Zelle's Python book.
The point of this is I need to loop my range for 5 instead of 4, however, because 'options' is in [i], this particular program above will pull:

```
    0: Hello
    1: How
    2: Are
    3: You
    4: ???
```

However, if I change the 4 to a 5, it will look for a 4th item in the list however it doesn't exist, so it will spit out an "IndexError: list index out of range"

What I want to achieve is, when the program reaches the end of the list, to loop back to the first (0) item in the list.

For example,

```
    for i in range(8):
```

Would pull out:

```
    0: Hello
    1: How
    2: Are
    3: You
    4: Hello
    5: How
    6: Are
    7: You
```

I have looked through this site and found some tools which haven't lead to any success, this includes the 'enumerate' function which I don't think will help.

If someone can shed some light on how to do this, it will be very welcome!
Hope I can do this without a nested loop aswell if this is at all possible.
Thanks you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this in one of two ways:

## 1. [`itertools.cycle`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)

```
c = itertools.cycle(options)
for i in range(anyNumber):
    message = Text(Point(x,y), next(c))
    message.draw(win)
    y = y + 30
```

## 2. modulus

```
for i in range(anyNumber):
    message = Text(Point(x,y), options[i%len(options)])
    message.draw(win)
    y = y + 30
```

**EDIT**:

From the conversation in the comments:

If you want to print the contents of the list 4 times here are a couple of ways to accomplish this:

```
options = ["Hello", "How", "Are", "You"]
for i in range(4):
    for e,elem in enumerate(options):
        print("%d: %s" %(4*i+e, elem))
```

OR

```
options = ["Hello", "How", "Are", "You"]
for e,elem in enumerate(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(options,4))):
    print("%d: %s" %(e, elem))
```

OR

```
options = ["Hello", "How", "Are", "You"]
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(len(options)):
        print("%d: %s" %(4*i+j, options[j]))
```

Comment: Thankyou everyone for you comments, especially you inspectorG4dget.

I was wondering if you could expand on the 'modulus' way of doing it!
If for example, in range(5):, would produce:
'code'
    0: Hello
    1: How
    2: Are
    3: You
    4: Hello
'code'
This is what I want but if I was to put this into a nested loop, It would put 0 & 4 which would produce 'Hello' twice in a row. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: @MikeShiner: what would you like it to output when it hits `4`?

Comment: Well 4 (Hello) would make the loop correct as 4 is supposed to be the same as 0, but in a nested loop, it will end on 4 and then redo the loop starting at 0 (which will make 'Hello' appear twice). I cannot see a way in which " len % " would work to stop this re-occurrence. Thus my next question, how would you cycle though a list in a nested loop (without the use of itertools). Thank you so much for your help.
Code I'm discussing:
`def real():
    options = ["Hello", "How", "Are", "You"]
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(5):
            print(options[i % len(options)])`

Comment: It looks like you want to print the contents of the list 4 times (that's the reason you have the outer `for i in range(4)` loop. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, print the content of the list 4 times but after the first 'j' loop, I don't want to print the last string from the list since it is the same as the first. So I want to escape my program from producing:
`Hello How Are You Hello Hello How Are You Hello Hello...` It is the double 'Hello' I am trying to get rid of, I only want the one. Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

options = ["Hello", "How", "Are", "You"]

for idx, option in enumerate(islice(cycle(options), 8)):
    print idx, option
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly loop over the values, not indices. Python is designed to avoid looping with indices, and doing so is awkward, inefficient and ugly:

```
for option in options:
    do_something(option)
```

is far better than:

```
for option_index in range(len(options)):
    do_something(options[option_index])
```

To get your looping behaviour, look at [itertools.cycle()](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat):

```
for option, _ in zip(itertools.cycle(options), range(x)):
    ...
```

Where `x` is the number of items you want. Here we use `range()` and `zip()` to stop repeating after the number of items is reached (throwing the values from range away).

Comment: @inspectorG4dget

I would like to do this the Modulo way, 
I was wondering if you could expand on the 'modulus' way of doing it!
If for example, in range(5):, would produce:

    0: Hello
    1: How
    2: Are
    3: You
    4: Hello

This is what I want but if I was to put this into a nested loop, It would put 0 & 4 with would produce 'Hello' twice in a row. Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the modulo (%) operator:

```
options = ["Hello", "How", "Are", "You"]
for i in range(8):
    print(options[i % len(options)])
```

yields

```
Hello
How
Are
You
Hello
How
Are
You
```